# How to run a method in the background in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, background

I have the login form as below. The worker can login and logout first time easily. The issue arrises when the worker logs out and tries to login again right away and I get the error drift is not defined. I want to add a delay to the drift part of the code but I don't want the worker to wait for the delay to be again to logged.

So something like 10 seconds or more delay but worker should not wait for login. Keeping on checking the drift in the background and run the drift part as it is available but it should not freeze the login. Help me achieve this

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 md7 lg8 >
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex md12 lg12>
            <div>
              <v-form :model='worker' ref='loginForm'>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                  <v-flex xs12 md6>
                    <v-text-field
                      label='Email Address'
                      v-model='worker.email'
                      name="email"
                      :rules='emailRules'
                      required>
                    </v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md6>
                    <v-text-field
                      label='Password'
                      v-model='worker.password'
                      name="password"
                      type='password'
                      :rules='passwordRules'
                      required>
                    </v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
                <v-btn @click='login'>Log In</v-btn>
              </v-form>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      worker: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      error: '',
      emailRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter your email address',
      ],
      passwordRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter a password'
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      var that = this;

      if (this.$refs.loginForm.validate()) {
        this.$axios.post('sign_in.json', { user: this.worker }).then(function(response) {
          drift.identify(response.data.worker.id, {
            email: response.data.worker.email
          })
          window.location.href = '/my_account';
        }).catch(function(error) {
          that.error = error;
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `drift` defined?

Comment: its a library, chatbox

Comment: Where/how is it defined in relation to the code that uses it?

Comment: it is installed using yarn, so when a user logs out and tries to login back right away, sometimes drift is not available it takes time to load. Since the time it is not available it stops the user from logging in. SO thats what I am trying to achiieve that when drift is not available user can still login and in the background send the worker details to drift when it is available

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with chatbox/drift, so I don't know how you are obtaining the 'drift' instance, but I think that you are going to have to add some sort of async check for the availability of the 'drift' instance, so something like

```
   login() {
          var that = this;
    
          if (this.$refs.loginForm.validate()) {
            this.$axios.post('sign_in.json', { user: this.worker }).then(async function(response) {
              await getDrift().identify(response.data.worker.id, {
                email: response.data.worker.email
              })
              window.location.href = '/my_account';
            }).catch(function(error) {
              that.error = error;
            });
          }
```